# Save and share image from project's assets in React Native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, save, share

Is it possible to save an image coming from project's assets folder in the gallery and/or share it using the Share api in React Native?
If not is it possible to do it natively in Android and iOS?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use [`react-native-share`](https://github.com/EstebanFuentealba/react-native-share) library, since the React Native's share library' features are limited, and **url sharing** is only supported in `IOS`

[Here](https://github.com/EstebanFuentealba/react-native-share#methods) are the useful methods available

- **url**: *URL you want to share (you can share a base64 file url only in iOS & Android*     `// You need this one.`

You can share via [base64](https://github.com/EstebanFuentealba/react-native-share#share-base-64-file) or [file url](https://github.com/EstebanFuentealba/react-native-share#share-file-directly) directly

The example is really simple to use

```
let shareImageBase64 = {
  title: "React Native",
  message: "Hola mundo",
  url: REACT_ICON,
  subject: "Share Link" //  for email
};

Share.open(shareImageBase64)
```